# Angular with nginx failing to communicate with backend(Golang)

Tags: angular, docker, go, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using nginx to serve angular(index.html) and that works fine. The issue is that I keep getting error when trying to communicate with my backend.

**My NGINX + Angular Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run ng build --prod

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/FrontEnd /var/www
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**My Golang Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest

ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build main.go

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "./main" ]
```

**My Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
      image: "postgres:latest"
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=Project
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      networks:
        - mynet

    #Back-end
    golang:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: golang
      links:
        - postgres  
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      networks:
        - mynet
    
    #Front-end Angular Application
    angular:
      links:
        - golang
      build:
        context: ./FrontEnd
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        - host=golang
      ports:
        - "4200:80"
      networks:
        - mynet

volumes:
  data:

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

**My nginx default.conf**

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /users {
            proxy_pass http://golang:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of when I try to send api call to golang
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQuhf.png

I've been stuck on this issue for several days now and is running low on time. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Angular Frontend is running on another machine (IP-address, Docker-Container) than the Backend. If FrontEnd connects to Backend it's like a remote machine connecting to Backend. So Backend (Golang-HTTP-Processing) panics because of CORS. You need to open up the IPs in Golang Backend sending CORS Headers. (Don't know how to do that, I only know it in NodeJS/Express, but the mechanism is the same)

Comment: How do you know its panicing? Like if I run docker-compose up to see different requests coming in. My Golang isn't even picking up any signals at all from Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`golang:8000` is only reachable in docker network. You could check your golang  API by visiting `http://35.238.xx.xx:4200/users/xxx` in browser, and use  relative url like `"/users/xxx"` in your angular code.

Comment: It's reachable in the browser but it's kind of meaningless since my angular program can't communicate with it. I have to manually change my apiUrl every time? but even then, I cant do that anyway because u can't pick up the IP address and rebuild the whole angular program.

Comment: You could define the API prefix as a global variable in HTML `<script>API_PREFIX='xxxxxxx';</script>` and use the variable in angular.

Comment: how would I pass ip address into API_PREFIX then?

Comment: Here you can use a relative path without IP `<script>API_PREFIX='/users/'</script>`, in your devlepment environment, it may like `<script>API_PREFIX='http://127.0.0.1:9999/'</script>`

Comment: yeah but i meant how would i be able to "feed IP" into angular because I'm trying to deploy it on a virtual machine. If I change IP address after built, it doesn't recompile I don't think.

Comment: If your html URL and API URL have save IP and port, relative URL is fine, otherwise you have to change the IP and port manually.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't have the same ip, otherwise "localhost" in the URL would've worked fine. Isnt the point of a dockercompose is that you don't have to do it manually tho?

Comment: Actually I fixed it. I just used the actually Virtual Machine's IP address. Kind of misunderstood ur answer a little bit.